# ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi'

Tags: python, ubuntu

Устанавливаю OPM (Open Porous Media) на WSL Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. Версия Python 3.9.13.

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:opm/ppa
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 68, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

Что делал:

- открыть файл и добавить .8 в названии `sudo vim /usr/bin/add-apt-repository` - не возможно редактировать название файла
- ```sh
  cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
  sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
  ```
- ```sh
  cd /usr/bin/
  rm python3
  ln -s python3.8 python3
  ```

ничего не помогает. Файл не доступен для редактирования.

Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная ошибка может возникать из-за конфликта версий пакетов Python и gi. Рекомендуется проверить, что все необходимые пакеты и зависимости установлены и обновлены.

Вы можете попробовать следующее:

1. Обновите все установленные пакеты:

   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
2. Попробуйте установить пакет gi отдельно:

   `sudo apt-get install python3-gi`
3. Попробуйте переустановить пакеты software-properties-common и
   python3-software-properties:

   `sudo apt-get remove software-properties-common python3-software-properties`

   `sudo apt-get autoremove`

   `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python3-software-properties`
4. Если ничего из вышеперечисленного не помогло, попробуйте
   переустановить Python:

   `sudo apt-get remove python3`

   `sudo apt-get autoremove`

   `sudo apt-get install python3`

   Затем повторите установку OPM.

Надеюсь, это поможет решить проблему.